# create tab delimited file for a quickbooks .iif file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, csv, quickbooks

I'm creating a Quickbooks .iif file with JavaScript, on the client side. It's for invoicing. I can't seem to generate the file correctly.

I'm matching a working .iif test file with the one I'm generated. I've inspected the working file with vim and found the tab delimiters, with an `^M` carriage return.  I've tried to write each row and put that into an array, to be joined together as a string with an `\n` newline. The file successfully imports into Quickbooks, but I can't find the invoice after Quickbooks prompts the successful invoice message.

it's basically like this:

```
formatInvoiceRows = () => {
  let invoiceRows = ["!TRNS\tTRNSID\tTRNSTYPE\tDATE\tACCNT\tNAME\tCLASS\tAMOUNT\tDOCNUM\tMEMO\tCLEAR\tTOPRINT\tADDR1\tADDR2\tADDR3\tADDR4\tADDR5\tDUEDATE\tTERMS\tPAID\tSHIPDATE","!SPL\tSPLID\tTRNSTYPE\tDATE\tACCNT\tNAME\tCLASS\tAMOUNT\tDOCNUM\tMEMO\tCLEAR\tQNTY\tPRICE\tINVITEM\tPAYMETH\tTAXABLE\tREIMBEXP\tEXTRA","!ENDTRNS"];

  // a bunch of data is mutated here, for each transaction row (excluded for brevity)

  // then push to array
  invoiceRows.push(mutatedData);
  invoiceRows.push('ENDTRNS');

  this.setState({ 
    invoiceData: invoiceRows 
  })
}
```

the program has to do a few things before it's ready to download, like call graphql to get more invoices, which will be pushed to invoiceRows

then:

```
createQuickbooksFile = () => {
    const { invoiceData, invoiceFileName } = this.state;

    // join each row with a new line
    let tsvRows = invoiceData.join('\n')

    this.downloadQuickbooksFile(`${invoiceFileName}.iif`, tsvRows)
  }
```

and finally:

```
downloadQuickbooksFile = (filename, tsvRows) => {
    var element = document.createElement('a');
    element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/tab-separated-values,' + encodeURIComponent(tsvRows));
    element.setAttribute('download', filename);

    element.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(element);

    element.click();

    document.body.removeChild(element);
  }
```

Comment: looking at my code, i think i can skip pushing the header to the invoiceRows and go ahead and include that in the invoiceRows to begin with...

Comment: !could also probably consolidate the two functions: 1) createQuickbooksFile() 2) downloadQuickbooksFile()